# Rerendering React.js When Browser Location Changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

I have a single page application using React.js.  When viewing new content, only certain elements on the page are being updated via React.  When this happens, I manually do the following (starting from the root location):

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "/page2");
```

to update the browser location.  However, when I click back, the url goes back to the previous url (i.e. "/") but the page doesn't update.

How do I listen for changes to the browser navigation (back/forward buttons) and rerender according to the updated URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router).

Pete Hunt uses director.js (sorry, can't post the url due to low reputation), which you can see in the ReactJS TodoMVC example [here](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react/js/app.jsx) in lines 29-34.